# If, then else statement for testing database name

Tags: database, if-statement

We run multiple databases for different companies and are trying to set up a template database that we know our standard sql scripts work on.

I have therefore written SQL scripts that I need to run on the multiple databases, however before running the script I need some code that will check the database name and if it is "xyz.db" then it will skip part of the code. (An if-else statement).

I have as a test tried this -

```
SELECT db_name()

If DB_NAME = 'callQATemplateDB'
  print db_name
else
  print 'not db'
```

however I am receiving the following error message - 
The name "db_name" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

DB_ID() also works, and you're not comparing strings so you don't have to consider DB collations:

```
IF DB_ID() = DB_ID('some_db') 
  SELECT 'GOOD DB' AS Msg
ELSE
  SELECT 'BAD DB !' AS Msg
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try putting the "()" on the end of DB_NAME?

```
SELECT DB_NAME();

If DB_NAME() = 'callQATemplateDB'
  print DB_NAME();
else
  print 'not db';
```

Unless you assign `DB_NAME()` to a variable, you cannot refer to it without "()".  So, you could do this:

```
declare @db_name sysname;
select @db_name = DB_NAME();

If @db_name = 'callQATemplateDB'
  print @db_name;
else
  print 'not db';
```